# Bad rendering with Barteksc AndroidPdfViewer

Tags: java, android, pdf, kotlin, rendering

I am using [Barteksc AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/) to load my applications PDFs.

The problem is that after I zoom in my loaded PDF, when it tries to render again, it just get blurry:

[image: Example]

Has anyone been using this library or knows a solution for this particular problem? I have tried using **.enableAntialiasing(true)** but it does not solve the problem.

**EDIT:**

These are the configurations I am using for my PDF View:

```
pdf_view.fromFile(temp)
        .enableSwipe(true)
        .swipeHorizontal(true)
        .enableDoubletap(true)
        .enableAntialiasing(true)
        .onPageChange(this)
        .onLoad(this)
        .onTap(this)
        .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.BOTH)
        .pageFling(true)
        .pageSnap(true)
        .autoSpacing(true)
        .load()
```

As for the PDF, sorry but I can't provide one. The PDF is downloaded in the application and has some method not created by me do decrypt the file. I just use the decrypted PDF, but I have a hint that the problem is not from the PDF itself since my coworker has this working in is iOS version with the same type of PDF.

Comment: What configurations are you using for pdfview and can you provide the pdf file used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using latest beta versions it have some bugs , try 2.8.2 stable version , i have used it in many applications i can tell from my experience that it its a problem of pdf or a particular phone

Comment: Was avoiding this solution since the new version (beta) comes with some methods I wanted to use, but seems this is the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think this section will help you : [github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/#double-tap-zooming](http://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/#double-tap-zooming)
You can set max zoom suitable to your needs.